# What is the relationship between topographic maps and sensory memory?

Tags: neuroscience, memory, cognitive-neuroscience

Sensory maps are defined functionally: they exist for a certain time window, are overwritten quickly, are generally inaccessible to introspective control.

Topographic maps are defined biologically: neurons within the map are organized spatially, so that nearby neurons store subtly different information.

Has the relationship between the two been studied in much detail?  Wikipedia tells me that the basis of, say, visual persistence iconic memory is neural persistence.  The kind of question I want an answer to: how adequately can the properties of various retinotopic maps explain known features of visual persistence iconic memory?